# Why do conditions in model associations not filter the find results in the controller in CakePHP?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.5

I have two models: `Users` and `Lessons`

- `User` has one `Teacher`
- `User` has and belongs to many `Students`

Both `Teachers` and `Students` are `Users`

In my `Users` model I have this association:

```
public $hasMany = array(
    'Lesson' => array(
        'className' => 'Lesson',
        'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
        'dependent' => false,
    )
);
```

In my `Lessons` model I currently have this association:

```
public $belongsTo = array(
    'Teacher' => array(
        'className' => 'User',
        'foreignKey' => 'teacher_id',
        'conditions' => array('Teacher.group_id' => '2'),
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => ''
    )
);
```

My questions are:

1. Why does `$teachers = $this->Lesson->Teacher->find('list');` return all the `users` and not just the `teachers`? Why don't the conditions set in the `belongsTo` part of the model filter the results to show only the `Users` with the `group_id` of 2 i.e. the `Teachers`? And if that's not the way it's supposed to work then what is the point of setting conditions here?

   As of now I have to include it in the find each time which seems kind of redundant: `$teachers = $this->Lesson->Teacher->find('list', array('conditions'=>array('Teacher.group_id'=>'2')))`
2. How do I write the associations for `Students` so that `Lessons` has many students? And how do I set up the database for it?

Comment: Regarding the database portion of your question: You need to share what your current tables _(users, teachers, students, lessons, users_teachers, etc.)_ are and  _(at a minimum)_ those table's primary and foreign keys. Your question is confusing because the statement "Users has one Teacher" implies 2 tables due to the use of the Cakephp terminology. But then your belongsTo relationship within the Lesson model describes Teachers as a subset of the User table.

Answer (score 0):

**1.** The condition in your association should be changed to include the Model's name rather than the alias:

```
'conditions' => array('User.group_id' => 2),
```

**2.** The association should be [hasAndBelongsToMany (HABTM)](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#hasandbelongstomany-habtm), and can be defined in your `User` model like this:

```
public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
    'Lessons' => array(
        'className' => 'Lesson',
        'joinTable' => 'lessons_users', // or the name from DB
        'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
        'associationForeignKey' => 'lesson_id',
        'unique' => 'keepExisting' // Set this based on your needs, check link above
    )
);
```

Given the association above, you need a new table `lessons_users` in your database to store data about this relationship between students and lessons:

```
          +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
          +  id (pk)  +  lesson_id (fk)  +  user_id (fk)  +
          +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
          +     1     +         1        +        1       +
          +-----------+------------------+----------------+
          +     2     +         1        +        2       +
          +-----------+------------------+----------------+
          +     3     +         2        +        1       +
          +-----------+------------------+----------------+
          +     4     +         2        +        2       +
          +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

From the example above; user with id 1 is taking lessons 1 & 2, and user with id 2 is taking lessons 1 & 2 as well. Likewise, lesson with id 1 has users with ids 1 & 2 enrolled, and lesson with id 2 has users with ids 1 & 2 enrolled as well.

Comment: 1) Changing the condition to use the model name instead of the alias results in a sql error (from what I understand CakePHP uses the alias in the query?)

2) How does this help me with accessing the Students in the Lesson model

Comment: **1)** I'm not sure exactly sure on this one, but I think you can't use the alias there because this is where you are defining the alias to begin with! **2)** You would have to add the same association (changing field names ofc) to your `lesson` model if you didn't have it there before, then use Containable behavior for both models to find your data. Check this [question on similar matter.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13826474/cakephp-containable-with-habtm "HABTM Containable")